# Effectively pick the variable with the min/max value that was assigned to it

Tags: algorithm

So if every variable has a value assigned to it ( I mean value is an attribute of variable) . How do i most efficiently pick out the variable that has the max or min value ?

Can you give an example in Python please ?
So this would be my approach in Python :

```
domains = []
for var in variables :
    domains.append(var.value)
min=  min(domains)
for var in variables :
    if var.value == min :
        return var
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide an example of your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+minimum+maximum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
domains.index(min(domains))
```

You may say that is not efficient but asymptotically you can't do any better when your list is not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

A general sketch would be something like this (improvements would be providing a way of extracting the wanted value, once you have a list, the actual element can easily be retrieved using the index):

```
def MinAndIndex(l):
  minval = l[0]
  min_ix = 0
  cnt = 0
  for e in l:
    if e < minval:
      minval = e
      min_ix = cnt
    cnt += 1

  return minval, min_ix
```